# is it possible to use excel VBA to write directly to chrome local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vba, excel

I'm writing some code that does some data visualization in HTML/Javascript. The data comes from Excel VBA which parses the data and writes the javascript code based on the data.  The process works fine but the size of the HTML file is over 240MB because of all of the thousands of html tables stored as variables the code creates.  Because of the file size, I don't have a program that can handle loading a file of this size to debug it.  Maybe there's a solution for that problem? otherwise I need a better solution.

In trying to streamline things a bit and make it easier to debug and I was wondering if it's possible to get my VBA code to write directly to my chrome browser local storage.  This way the HTML code is cleaner and a lot easier to debug and alter in Dreamweaver.

Please comment on a strategy that may work.  Since I'm not sure it will work or not, I'm reluctant to write code that has no chance of working.

Is this strategy just the wrong way of looking at it?  Is it faster to load from local storage or is it faster to load variables from a text file?  Should I have VBA create a text file that is then loaded into local storage when the HTML file is opened?

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Do you really need all of that data all at once?

Comment: Yes. It's a complex '4D' block model with a long time component.

Comment: Write the data to a linked js file - that wil keep it out of the main HTML page (though it's difficult based on your question to tell what you're really doing in that page...)

Comment: I have three html tables that represent a plan view, x-section view and y-section view.   For every X,Y,Z and Time I have a set of tables saves as variables.  When you navigate through the X,Y,Z, and Time a table is loaded representing the requested visualization.  Is it going to slow the HTML down if it has to load the data from the external file?  Is that faster than accessing local storage? I guess I could do this temporarily for debugging purposes.

Comment: Once the linked file is loaded then it's in-memory: it's not going back to disk each time you access data from the file.

Comment: I'm storing the html tables as properly formatted html tables which is a lot of text.  Is there another method for using html table data in a different form then convert it on the fly?  Or would this slow things down too much? As it is right now, everything loads quickly and smoothly. I'm afraid that if I have to transform data that things will become very sluggish.

Comment: As has been mentioned you definitely want to write the data to a separate 'linked' js file and just include it via a `<script>` before your JavaScript in your HTML. Also, you'd have trouble storing more than 5-10MB of data in localStorage, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to easily write directly to local storage from outside of chrome. Also the cap for local storage is under 50mb, there is no way you'll fit 240 mbps in there. If you did want to load into local storage you could have a loader script that you attach to the webpage. First time you access the page it would load the data in but this will only work for smaller datasets.

By the sound of this, js/html isn't the best choice but if that is how you want to go if you do not have a ssd then i am going to guess the bottleneck is the hard drive speed, not ram or processing power. It might be worth wrong the data to json as it will be a smaller file. Then you can convert into html tables after you load the separate Json/js file.

Another thought is multiple json files instead of one large one. The web is a wonderful asynchronous world, the hard drive isn't. Request to load each file separately, as they finish loading, display their data. This way each file contains a single visual element that is displayed.

Last thought, does this really need to be in html tables? Who wants to see 240mb of data on one page? I know i would rather have is separated into meaningful pages.